# Reset network settings to what Ubuntu installs

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, android

The problem is I messed up lots of files (such as `networkmanager.conf`) and other because my laptop was not connecting to an ad hoc network, it connected to other hotspots like my androids shared internet. After I  kept messing with the files, it does connect to a wifi but I can't access the Internet.

How can I reset the network settings to what is installed by default (AKA factory reset network settings)? I have tried lots of commands but nothing has worked. I am using Ubuntu 15.04

Answer (score 0):

You can try to flush the IP tables with
'sudo iptables -F'

If it doesn't work, you can als try to remove the relevant config files from '~/.config'

Comment: I've already tried this... still nothing

Comment: Is the problem also present when you use new account on your pc?

Comment: Yes ive tried from guest account still the same problem

Comment: About the relevant cofig files which file should i try to remove?

Comment: If the problem also excists when you use another account, deleting files in ~/.config or ~/.local will not help. They contain configuration settings for a specific account. I guess that your problem is more of a driver issue. Have you installed any proprietary drivers? I also recommend to use a wifi receiver if your built in ethernet card is not (well) supported by the current linux drivers.

Comment: My suggestion is that you read this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConfigurationCommandLine/Automatic